# VSCode - Shows Deploy to Function App, instead of Deploy to Web App for blazor (ASP.Net) webapp

Tags: visual-studio-code, deployment, blazor, blazor-server-side

VSCode sees my Blazor server app as an Azure Function. Right-clicking on my `publish` folder I only have the option to `Deploy to Function App`, instead of `Deploy to Web App` which logically shows me only my function apps from azure. How is this determined by VSCode? I have checked the project file, but I do not see anything obvious wrong.

I tried Googling this, but the search terms only brings me to tutorials where this problem does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the Azure Web App extension. Once that was installed, the option appeared